# kill application remotely

Tags: windows, command-line, java, remote

I have `sth.bat` file which launches my java program on computer A.

I start this application from computer B by using `psstart \\computerA "c:\sth.bat"`.

But I when it comes to kill it in the same way, I'm limited with the process name. Because when `sth.bat` is run, I see a `cmd.exe` and `java.exe` in process list.

I have to use the process name with `pskill \\computerA processName`. But I have more than one applications named `cmd.exe` and `java.exe`.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Look at calling `psexec` from SysInternals and doing a `tasklist` and and kill via that.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the start command in your `sth.bat` to start your java program, this allows you to specify a window title which you can supply to the `taskkill` command for a remote kill.

`tasklist /v` command reveals window titles.